# Django - handling a large number of forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm starting to work on a website, which obviously will have a ton of buttons, and I still only have 2 buttons to handle, and one of my views already has this piece of code to handle just those two form submissions

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if "see" in request.POST:
        seetagform = SeeTagForm(request.POST)
        createform = CreateForm()
        if seetagform.is_valid():
            cd = seetagform.cleaned_data
            tagstring = "_".join(cd["name"].split(' '))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("base:see",args=(tagstring,)))
    elif "create" in request.POST:
        createform = CreateForm(request.POST)
        seetagform = SeeTagForm()
        if createform.is_valid():
            cd = createform.cleaned_data
            p = Event.objects.create(start=cd["datetime"])
            tags = cd["tags"]
            tags = tags.split(' ')
            for tag in tags:
                t = Tag.objects.get(name=tag)
                t.events.add(p)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("base:see",args=(tagstring,)))

    else:
        createform = CreateForm()
        seetagform = SeeTagForm()

else:
    createform = CreateForm()
    seetagform = SeeTagForm()
```

Well, as far as I can sense, these are many if's and else's for only 2 buttons (but everything here is needed), so I wonder the confusion it might be when I have like 12 buttons across my page. This doesn't look too pythonic!
Is there a simpler/more clever way to handle many form submissions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it also that way, just adding prefix to the buttons name to be more clear

`@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    message = None
    user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    addresses = user.profile_address.all()
    AddressFormSet = modelformset_factory(Address, fields=['city','zip_code','address','phone','default_address',
                                                           'first_name','last_name'])
    address_formset = AddressFormSet(queryset=addresses)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=user)
    pass_form = PasswordChangeForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'btn_profile' in request.POST:
            profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user)
            if profile_form.is_valid():
                profile_form.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Successfully changed your profile')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
        if 'btn_pass' in request.POST:
            pass_form = PasswordChangeForm(request.POST)
            if pass_form.is_valid():
                user.set_password(pass_form.cleaned_data['password1'])
                user.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Successfully changed your password')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
        if 'btn_address' in request.POST:
            address_formset = AddressFormSet(request.POST)
            if address_formset.is_valid():
                for address_form in address_formset:
                    if address_form.is_valid()  and address_form.has_changed():
                        address = address_form.save(commit=False)
                        address.user_profile = user
                        address.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
    orders = Order.objects.filter(user = user).order_by('-created')
    context = {
        'address_formset': address_formset,
        'pass_form': pass_form,
        'profile_form':profile_form,
        'message':message,
        'orders':orders,
    }
    return render(request,'custom_auth/profile.html', context)`